# /dev/root is full and deleting files did not help

Tags: disk-usage

/dev/root is full for absolutely no apparent reason.

"df -h" gives:

```
Filesystem                                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                                                                20G   19G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                                                                 32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                    32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                    32G  2.0M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                                    32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdd1                                                               1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /media/sdd1
/dev/md2                                                                256G  237G  6.3G  98% /home
/dev/sdc1                                                               1.8T  961G  780G  56% /media/sdc1
tmpfs                                                                   6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
xxxxxxx.ovh.net:/export/ftpbackup/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  500G  438G   63G  88% /media/recovery
```

I deleted a bunch of log files and /dev/root is still at 100%.

"du -sch /*" gives:

```
13M     /bin
20M     /boot
0       /dev
11M     /etc
236G    /home
132M    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K     /lost+found
1.4T    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
```

/media contains some mounted disks.
/home is another mounted disk.

More information with the three following commands:

du -a --exclude=./home/* --exclude=./media/* | sort -nr | head -n 50:

```
du: cannot access ‘./proc/9221/task/9221/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/9221/task/9221/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/9221/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/9221/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
2763728 .
1420340 ./usr
1020940 ./var
713876  ./var/lib
657508  ./usr/lib
386408  ./var/lib/apt
386336  ./var/lib/apt/lists
375756  ./usr/share
287900  ./var/log
273512  ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

lsof | grep deleted

```
dovecot    2981                  root  123u      REG               0,16        0      17700 /run/dovecot/login-master-notifya6da78e256a4d799 (deleted)
dovecot    2981                  root  126u      REG               0,16        0      17702 /run/dovecot/login-master-notify306e18b42143ac3c (deleted)
squid3     3012                  root    3u      REG                9,1    12288     261210 /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1 (deleted)
squid3     3014                 proxy    3u      REG                9,1    12288     261210 /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1 (deleted)
apache2    5667                  root   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    5667                  root   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    5667                  root   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5667                  root   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5667                  root   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5709              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    5709              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    5709              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5709              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5709              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5710              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    5710              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    5710              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5710              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    5710              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    7171              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    7171              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    7171              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    7171              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    7171              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8531              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8531              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8531              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8531              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8531              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8532              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8532              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8532              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8532              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8532              www-data   17wW     REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8533              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8533              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8533              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8533              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8533              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8536              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8536              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8536              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8536              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8536              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8537              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8537              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8537              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8537              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8537              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8538              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8538              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8538              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8538              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8538              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8683              www-data   13u      REG                9,1        0     261317 /tmp/.ZendSem.YO4QIp (deleted)
apache2    8683              www-data   14w      REG               0,17        0   23690739 /run/lock/apache2/ssl-cache.5626 (deleted)
apache2    8683              www-data   15w      REG               0,17        0   23690743 /run/lock/apache2/proxy.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8683              www-data   16w      REG               0,17        0   23690744 /run/lock/apache2/rewrite-map.5667 (deleted)
apache2    8683              www-data   17w      REG               0,17        0   23690747 /run/lock/apache2/mpm-accept.5667 (deleted)
```

more /etc/mtab

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=32931784k,nr_inodes=8232946,mode=755 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=28,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
sunrpc /run/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /media/sdd1 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/md2 /home ext4 rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/sdc1 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/0 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6593060k,mode=700 0 0
xxxxxxxxxxxxx.net:/export/ftpbackup/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/recovery nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=524288,wsize=524288,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=
600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=xx.xx.xx.xx,mountvers=3,mountport=53313,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=xx.xx.xx.xx 0 0
```

Comment: Just wondering: In your /etc/mtab you have `errors=remount-ro`. Was there an error at mount? On my system I don't have an entry for rootfs - is it normal to have both rootfs and /dev/root mounted on / ?

Comment: Not sure how I could check for errors at mount. Especially since it can't write to log files because disk is full.. For "errors=remount-ro", it's been in the fstab since I got the server. Never had a problem before.

Comment: Another idea: As you have mountpoints /media/sdda, /home and /media/sdc1 it is possible that there are data in these directories that you currently cannot see because they are hidden by the mounted filesystems. I would try to umount these filesystems and then take a look at the mountpoints.

Comment: ok found it. Unmounted /media/recovery, and the files were still there. But for much more than 20Go, so I don't understand how they could fit..? Anyway /dev/root is not full anymore, thank you.